# Using pywinauto to automate an MSI installer

Tags: python, windows-installer, pywinauto

I am looking at using pywinauto in python to automate the installation of a Windows MSI installer for testing purposes.

When I try to launch the MSI through the application.start I get the following error:

"Error returned by CreateProcess: [Error 193] "

Is it possible to even do this, or do I need to launch the MSI first and then connect to it, and if so, how do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to launch "msiexec.exe" and pass the MSI as a command line parameter for it to be installed. You cannot launch directly an MSI as you would launch an EXE file.

Example: msiexec.exe /i [MSI_path]